# Rails - How to create a desktop application?

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to transform a rails application to a desktop application? And if yes what is the best way of doing it.

And where should I start if I just want to create an simple windows desktop application that shows a few columns from a Mysql Database and check if they have changed.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, and even if it was, you'd be much more wise to use a framework designed for desktop applications

Comment: I have seen this http://cossincalc.com/

Comment: It looks like the app downloaded from that site only uses Ruby, not Rails.

Comment: How do I create an desktop app with Ruby ?

Comment: @Rails beginner I posted a good example of how Ruby can be used to create a desktop application. (I think you can use the `activerecord` Rails gem as well so you can keep your existing data layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform in the literal sense, no, no such tech exists. However, you can make a rails app that's live on the web, or any other web application appear somewhat like a desktop application (with its own icon, and even some OS integration) by using a "Site Specific Browser"

OSX: http://fluidapp.com/

Windows (and OSX): https://mozillalabs.com/prism

Comment: Prism got some really great features. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Prism is dead unfortunately, and all its spin-off projects are too (apparently the fast release cycle made it too hard to keep up with)

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be possible to use activerecord but you would need to do something different when dealing with the presentation layer. Maybe run your application using JRuby (see the gem `redcar` for a good example of how to implement a desktop application in Ruby/Java)

There are a few things to consider:
Do I just want this to run using a specific window manager?
Is it important for this to be cross platform?

My guess is that you would want to JRuby in conjunction with SWT and then reuse your data layer (models etc).

I think it could be done but you will have to pick and choose from some of Rails' sub-gems.

Answer (score -1):

Rails, no, but Ruby can be used for this. I would take a look at [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) for that. Write you app in Ruby but run it on java and access all the libraries it has. [FXRuby](http://www.fxruby.org/) is also an option.
[Rhodes](http://rhomobile.com/products/rhodes/) is supposed to be MVC and close to Rails but I don't know how close. Its intended for mobile apps though.

Comment: The OP is asking how to transform a rails app.

Answer (score -2):

This won't be direct. Desktop apps coud be done using shoes which is a really great tool.

Here is a basic example:

```
Shoes.app :width => 300, :height => 200 do
  button("Click me!") { alert("Good job.") }
end
```

They provide many apps examples here: http://the-shoebox.org/

And for basic examples: https://github.com/ashbb/shoes_tutorial_walkthrough

For more details see: http://shoesrb.com/

Comment: The OP is asking how to transform a rails app. To use shoes, you have to rewrite from scratch.